# PHPSESSID and cURL

Tags: curl, web-scraping, php

I'd like to get a list of games from this website 
http://www.basket.ee/
Hooaeg: 2012/2013 -> G4S KML -> Ajakava/tulemused -> põhiturniir

It's possible to access the page by entering this URL http://www.basket.ee/index.php?mid=469&round=1&sid=2013&chid=001&tase=1 however you need to fetch the PHPSESSID cookie first.
I was unable to do so. Do you have any idea, how to get this cookie?

Comment: There is an firefox addon called, 'Tamper Data', use it to find session and cookies then use CURL to to access the page and keep the session active.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use curl to store cookiedata (and session stuff). SO basically, you visit the mainsite first and then goto the suburl. Example code:

```
$mainurl = "http://www.basket.ee/"
$ripurl = "http://www.basket.ee/index.php?mid=469&round=1&sid=2013&chid=001&tase=1"
//Put cookie file
$cookieFile = "cookie.txt";

//if file doesn't exist
if(!file_exists($cookieFile)) {
    //fopen for writing
    $fh = fopen($cookieFile, "w");
    //write
    fwrite($fh, "");
    //close
    fclose($fh);
}

//Start session for first login
$ch = curl_init();
//Load curl
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $mainurl);
//Set cookie file
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieFile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFile);
//do not return data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//execute curl and close
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

//startup curl again
$ch = curl_init($urlxml);
//cookie stuff
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieFile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFile);

//store curl result in var
$rawdata=curl_exec($ch);

//Close curl
curl_close ($ch);

echo $rawdata;
```

Using this your storing the session into a cookie var. Which makes the user believe you're a normal user browsing.

Comment: That's right, but I should be able to see that variable when using CURLOPT_HEADER=>1 option, right? Unfortunately it didn't seem to be useful.

Comment: You can read out the cookie var. Can i ask why you exactly need the session id?

Comment: Of course I have tried such a code you posted, but it didn't work because of the missing session ID. You can try to open a browser go to the main page, then paste the above mentioned URL.

Comment: It'll only work if some other cookies/ POST variables are set e.g. CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>'periodSelector=2013', but that's not the point. The most important is the session ID

Answer (score -2):

You can try on the terminal

```
curl -v  http://www.basket.ee/
```

Or you can try to see if you can get the information in one of the files that appear in `Network` of the `Inspect Element` option in Chrome.